# React Countdown Timer unable to make a stop function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am practically new to React. In this App I am using Hooks!
I've made a Countdown Timer that will show in a few seconds after logging in. I am unable to make it stop on a button click. I need some advise on this as I've been struggling for the past 2 days with this.
This is my code so far: (Please Help)

```
function Admin() {
    const [isTimerOpen, setTimmer] = useState(false);
    let history = useHistory();

    // SET BY THE ADMIN
    var minutesToCountDown = 0.9;
    // TRANSFORM INTO SECONDS
    var transformMinutesToSeconds = minutesToCountDown * 60
    // KEEP A STATE
    const [counterValue, setCounterValue] = useState(0);
    const [isTimmerStoped, setStopTimer] = useState(false);

    // FUNCTION TO HAPPEN EVERY 1 SECOND
    function timeIt() {
        if (isTimmerStoped === false) {
            transformMinutesToSeconds--
            setCounterValue(transformMinutesToSeconds)
            console.log("Timer is on: ", transformMinutesToSeconds)

            if (transformMinutesToSeconds === 0) {
                clearInterval(interval)
                setStopTimer(true)
            }
        } else {
            setStopTimer(true)
            clearInterval(interval)
        }
    }

    // STARTS THE COUNTDOWN
    var interval;
    const startCountdown = () => {
        interval = setInterval(timeIt, 1000)
    }

    const stopCountdown = () => {
        console.log("Stop Timer")
        setStopTimer(true);
        setCounterValue(0);
        setTimmer(false);
    }

    // ADD 0 IN FRONT ON THE TIME REMAINING
    const addLeadingZeros = value => {
        value = String(value);
        while (value.length < 2) {
            value = `0${value}`;
        }
        return value;
    };

    // CONVERT SECONDS INTO TIME REMAINING
    function convertSeconds(seconds) {
        var min = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
        var sec = seconds % 60;
        return addLeadingZeros(min) + ':' + addLeadingZeros(sec)
    }

    const logOutUser = () => {
        logout();
        return history.push(mainRoute)
    }

    function setTimer() {
        const timer = setTimeout(() => {
            setTimmer(true)
            console.log('This will run after 3 seconds!')
            startCountdown()

        }, sessionTimeout);
        return () => clearTimeout(timer);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (isTimmerStoped === false) {
            console.log('Effect Starting', isTimmerStoped)
            setTimer()
        } else {
            console.log('Effect Stopping', isTimmerStoped)
            stopCountdown()
        }

      }, [isTimmerStoped, setStopTimer, minutesToCountDown]);



    return <React.Fragment>
            <CssBaseline />
            <Container disableGutters maxWidth={false}>
                <NavigationBar handleSignOut={logOutUser}/>
                <TimerContent 
                    timeRemaining={convertSeconds(counterValue)}
                    isTimerAlertOpen={isTimerOpen}
                    extendSessionBtn={stopCountdown}
                    logoutBtn={logOutUser}  
                    clickOutsideButton={stopCountdown}/>
            </Container>
    </React.Fragment>  
}

export default Admin;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do 2 things.

1. Make the `interval` variable a ref. This way it's value will be unique every where it imported. Note: Just creating a variable above the component is a bad idea because that variable will be shared between each component that imports the `Admin` component, which will lead to bugs.

### Wrong

```js
let interval;

function Admin() {
  //... code here

  // STARTS THE COUNTDOWN
  // var interval; Remove from here
  const startCountdown = () => {
      interval = setInterval(timeIt, 1000)
  }

  //... code here
}

export default Admin;
```

### Right

```js
function Admin() {
  const interval = React.useRef(); 
  //... code here

  // STARTS THE COUNTDOWN
  // var interval; Remove from here
  const startCountdown = () => {
      interval.current = setInterval(timeIt, 1000)
  }

  //... code here
}

export default Admin;
```

2. Add `clearInterval` to your `stopCountdown` function. You can remove the clearInterval in the `timeIt` function and move it into `stopCountdown`. Please take a look at this [codepen](https://codepen.io/RB_Projects/pen/GRpypMe) I made to demostrate

```js
const stopCountdown = () => {
  console.log("Stop Timer")
  setStopTimer(true);
  setCounterValue(0);
  setTimmer(false);
  clearInterval(interval.current) // Clear the interval here
}
```

Comment: Cheers, it worked perfectly! I used the clear interval in the stopCountdown function before but the thing I never thought about is to take the interval outside of the function. Thanks!

Comment: This would fail as soon as more than one `Admin` component gets rendered since `interval` would be shared (overwritten) by all `Admin` components.

Comment: @EmileBergeron That is not true. If the `Admin` component is in a different file from where you are using it, the interval value will be different for each `Admin` instance. I made a demo https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-violet-po3zu?file=/src/Admin.js

Comment: Your codesandbox doesn't work, the stop button isn't even wired to anything and even if it was, it doesn't work because the state is captured by the closure (setInterval callback) and never gets the updated state value needed to stop...

Comment: ohhh and it does exactly what I predicted. When multiple intervals are running, only the last one stops when the first one reaches zero.

Comment: Yes you are right, I have updated the code in my sandbox and updated my answer to use useRef. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't maintain the intervalId returned by setInterval in a functional variable since it will be reset on re-render and you will loose the actual timer Id. You must instead use `useRef` hook to store the timerId

```
   const interval = useRef(null);
    ...
   function timeIt() {
        if (isTimmerStoped === false) {
            transformMinutesToSeconds--
            setCounterValue(transformMinutesToSeconds)
            console.log("Timer is on: ", transformMinutesToSeconds)

            if (transformMinutesToSeconds === 0) {
                clearInterval(interval.current)
                setStopTimer(true)
            }
        } else {
            setStopTimer(true)
            clearInterval(interval.current)
        }
    }
    ...
   // STARTS THE COUNTDOWN
    const startCountdown = () => {
        interval.current = setInterval(timeIt, 1000)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the answer, and you are right the interval shouldn't be kept inside the function... Realised that now, but the useRef for some reason is not working for me. The other solution worked. Thank you anyway, it is much appreciated!

Comment: Moving the interval value outside of the component means you are limited to using just 1 instance of your component which may suffice for you for now, but isn't the correct approach. Right way is to use useRef. Maybe you weren't using ` interval.current` which caused a problem